# Is it possible to make user-defined KIND parameters globally available?

Tags: fortran

Consider the following code:

```
module numbers
    integer, parameter :: sing_prec = selected_real_kind(6)
    integer, parameter :: doub_prec = selected_real_kind(15)
end module
```

Whenever I want to use variables of type `real(sing_prec) :: foo` or similar somewhere within my code, I need to insert `use numbers` in the respective program unit. Is it possible to do that in a "global" fashion, i.e. make the KIND definitions globally available?

Are there any implications to this? If the types are required in many places, inserting use statements everywhere makes the code quited bloated. Something similiar to compiler flags such as `-fimplicit none` in gfortran for imposing `implicit none`everywhere would be great, but I was not able to find such a flag.

This question is not restricted to a specific Fortran version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard Fortran - No.

In compiler specific implementations of Fortran - Not as far as I am aware with the current crop of widely used compilers.  All (?) have options to treat default reals (integers, complexes, too) as either 4- or 8-byte, but not to selectively treat some as 4- and some as 8- (or whatever lengths you wish to make use of).

You could hack it I guess -- maybe put all code in one scope ?

*Arrrgggh* you recoil in horror, *all the code in one scope !!!*

which kind of takes me to this point =>  Most recent programming languages and systems have tended towards increasing modularisation and think it a *good thing* to explicitly *import* definitions from one scope to another. Fortran uses `use` but other similar mechanisms in other languages go under the labels of `import`, `include`, and similar.

By the way, you do know about the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env` don't you ?  You might rewrite your snippet along the lines

```
use iso_fortran_env, sing_prec => real32, doub_prec => real64
```

Comment: I have corrected my question. Of course, if I select a real kind I don't want to use that kind for an integer variable. That's why I was talking about precision :-) And yes, I am aware of the F08 `iso_fortran_env` but unfortunately I am stuck to some old F95 compiler which is also giving me a lot of other headaches. I think your answer clarified my question and it seems like I will be left to introduce a lot of `use` statements for my code refactoring... thanks!

Comment: I've correctified my answer to reflect OP's correction of the question.

Comment: @andreee : You don't need to add `use` statement to all your functions or subroutine, just add it once to the beginning of the module containing the functions/subroutines.

Comment: Yes - I should have mentioned that I am stuck with a code which was written in F77 originally and therefore many subroutines reside in a global scope rather than within a module definition. It would be much easier to solve the problem otherwise.