# Fortran link modules for precision and global variable types

Tags: module, fortran, gfortran

I am new to Fortran and trying to understand if the following is possible. My idea to structure the program is to declare the precision and variable types in one module. Then make use of those variables without declaring again the type in other modules or the main program.

```
module pre
implicit none

    INTEGER, PARAMETER      ::  sp=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(6,37)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER      ::  dp=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,307)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER      ::  qp=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(33,4931)

    REAL(dp), PARAMETER     ::  pi = 4.*ATAN(1.)
    REAL(dp)                ::  H                              
    REAL(dp)                ::  M 
    REAL(dp)                ::  KR 

end module pre
```

Now I want to make use of all the variables in another module that contains one or more functions, such as:

```
module hon
use pre
implicit none

contains
    function KE(H,M) result(KR)
        KR = 2*PI/H/M
    end function KE
end module hon
```

Then I use gfortran in this order:

```
gfortran -c mod_pre.f90
gfortran -c mod_hon.f90
```

Since 'module pre' is part of 'module hon' I compile in order, but gfortran shows an error.

With the code above I understand the variable types and parameters should have been included by **USE**; But the message I get from **gfortran** is that none of my variables have IMPLICIT type when I try to compile 'module hon'.

Could somebody clarify the problem or suggest a solution? I would like to avoid having my variables scattered in multiple modules.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the function statement, the `result(kr)` says that the function result has name `kr`.  This function result is not the same thing as the module variable `kr`.  In particular, this function result makes inaccessible the module variable.

The function result is specific to the function itself and its properties must be declared within the function subprogram.

Similarly, the dummy arguments of the function, `H` and `M`, are distinct from the module variables and need to be declared in the function subprogram.

Beyond that, you perhaps have similar concerns to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45854826).

To be clear, it isn't possible to say something like "all function results called `kr` and all dummy arguments called `H` or `M` have these characteristics".  Each individual object must be given the properties.

However, although I don't recommend this, this is a situation where literal text inclusion (using a preprocessor or include file) could help you:

```
function ke(H, M) result (kr)
   include 'resdummydecls'
   ...
end function
```

where the file has the declarations.

Comment: Hello francescalus, please bear with me. Then there is no use on declaring the variable types and using that module into others? For example the result 'kr' will always be a real(dp) and also the rest of the input variables. This would mean I need to declare 'H' or any other in every single module instead of just defining it once?

Comment: In your example, sp, dp and qp can be used as follows: `real(kind=dp) :: ke` to define the function kind. The *variable* `kr` as @francescalus mentions, is redefined as being local. The module-scoped `kr` will be used if no local `kr` is defined.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers, I had worked around the solution and the only way I found is to redefine the variables inside the function. I am facing now another problem regarding the function as gfortran states I am passing on of the variables REAL(4) to REAL(8). I am finding it a bit challenging to get started. Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Yes, @musi, you have to _define_ (not redefine) the variables within the functions: they exist only in the context of the function.  (Technically, "declare", not "define ".). Regarding the `real(4)` and `real(8)` issue: you need to declare appropriately what gets passed into the function also.